# Why height in percentage shrinks the adjacent divs to same heights?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make adjacent `div's` of different heights just like a vertical bar-graph. Problem is that when I specify div heights in px the `div's` height is [ok](https://jsfiddle.net/4amv0ccx/1/)  but when i specify heights in different percentage then all the adjacent `div's` shrink to same height. I specified min-height to the container `div` and the bars `div's` but it still does'nt work. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="barcontainer">
<div id="firstbar" class="bar" style= "height:10%">
&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="secondbar" class="bar" style= "height:80%">
&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="thirdbar" class="bar" style= "height:50%">
&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="fourthbar" class="bar" style= "height:30%">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
barscontainer
{
  min-height: 300px;
}
.bar{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7EADCB;
  border-bottom: medium none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
  min-height: 1px
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Please guide me what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add your css for the broken case?

Comment: I hope someone with more knowledge can either confirm or deny this, but I read that CSS lengths as a percentage, is the percentage of the width, *even for height values*. Probably doesn't relate to this case but it reminded me....

Answer (score 1):

The `div`s shrink as the `barcontainer` height will be a few pixels unless you `clear` the float and set a height for your `barcontainer`- the percentages will work now as expected. Cheers!

```css
.barcontainer{
   height: 300px;
  }
.barcontainer:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.bar {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7EADCB;
  border-bottom: medium none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
  min-height: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="barcontainer">
  <div id="firstbar" class="bar" style="height:10%">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id="secondbar" class="bar" style="height:80%">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id="thirdbar" class="bar" style="height:50%">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div id="fourthbar" class="bar" style="height:30%">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

@Martin 's comment got me thinking. And here in SO itself in an another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309205/height-calculation-by-browsers-containing-blocks-and-children) (thanks to @JohanKarlsson) I was looking why it happens that you specify `min-height` and the children do not respect them when you give percentage heights:

The **height** CSS [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) says:

> **Percentages**
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. **If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto.** A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

So it look like (though I still have some doubts) that here the **height** attribute of the parent isn't *explicitly* specified, therefore the value computes to **auto**- the `min-height` overrides `height` but `height` is still not *explicitly* specified.

Comment: @TheNoble-Coder check out the update answer- `min-height` does not work for you (you have to specify `height` too) because that is how CSS works...

Comment: @TheNoble-Coder following up on this... please accept / upvote the answer if you found this helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few things I can see:

1. The class selector is incorrect: should be `.barcontainer`.
2. If the `min-height` attribute on the `barcontainer` class is set to `height` with a length value (like 300px or 30em), the bars are the correct length. I suspect the problem is the empty content.
3. The non-breaking spaces need to be wrapped in something (a `p` tag will do).
4. You can do the inline style, but I might apply that in the CSS using ID selectors.

Here's a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9zcso4mt/) showing those changes. I noticed that when running this on a MacBook Pro Retina, because of the pixel density, 300px isn't especially tall.

Another way to do this might be to use SVGs, depending on your needs. I've used them to good effect in a couple of things like this. There are some examples of how to make bar charts [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-charts-with-svg/).