# Height Calculation By Browsers : Containing Blocks and Children

Tags: html, css

Picked up this in SO itself - the 'height calculation' made by browsers (when we have not explicitly set a `height` but we have set a `min-height`) for a *container* that has *children* (who have height in percentages with respect to the container):

1. Without setting a height, I set `min-height` and it doesn't work- note that the computed value of height is the value I gave for `min-height`. The children do not get 50% height that I have given them - see below:

   ```css
       * {
             box-sizing: border-box;
           }
           .inline-container,
           .block-container,
           .float-container,
           .inline-block-container {
             border: 1px solid red;
             min-height: 100px;
           }
           .inline-container > * {
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
           .block-container > * {
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
           .float-container > * {
             float: left;
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
           .float-container:after {
             clear: both;
             content: '';
             display: block;
           }
           .inline-block-container > * {
             display: inline-block;
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
   ```

   ```html
       <body>
             <div class="inline-container">
               <span>Inline 1</span>
               <span>Inline 2</span>
             </div>
             <div class="block-container">
               <div>Block 1</div>
               <div>Block 2</div>
             </div>
             <div class="float-container">
               <div>Float 1</div>
               <div>Float 2</div>
               <div>Float 3</div>
             </div>
             <div class="inline-block-container">
               <div>Inline block 1</div>
               <div>Inline block 2</div>
               <div>Inline block 3</div>
             </div>
           </body>
   ```
2. Now I set `height: 0` it works! See example below:

   ```css
       * {
             box-sizing: border-box;
           }
           .inline-container,
           .block-container,
           .float-container,
           .inline-block-container {
             border: 1px solid red;
             min-height: 100px;
             height: 0;
           }
           .inline-container > * {
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
           .block-container > * {
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
           .float-container > * {
             float: left;
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
           .float-container:after {
             clear: both;
             content: '';
             display: block;
           }
           .inline-block-container > * {
             display: inline-block;
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 50%;
           }
   ```

   ```html
       <body>
             <div class="inline-container">
               <span>Inline 1</span>
               <span>Inline 2</span>
             </div>
             <div class="block-container">
               <div>Block 1</div>
               <div>Block 2</div>
             </div>
             <div class="float-container">
               <div>Float 1</div>
               <div>Float 2</div>
               <div>Float 3</div>
             </div>
             <div class="inline-block-container">
               <div>Inline block 1</div>
               <div>Inline block 2</div>
               <div>Inline block 3</div>
             </div>
           </body>
   ```

**Question:**

So my question is- what is happening here- I am really surprised! Why the children are not respecting the computed height of the containing block when I give it a min-height. Can you guys look into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **height** CSS property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> **Percentages**
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. **If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto.** A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

In `1.`, the **height** attribute of the parent isn't explicitly specified, therefore  the value computes to **auto**.

In `2.`, the **height** attribute is specified and therefore it's calculated with respect to the parent

Comment: but for `1.`, I checked the computed height by inspecting in browser and it gives me the value I set for `min-height` and is not `auto`

Comment: @kukkuz `min-height` overrides `height`. `height` is still not **explicitly** specified.

Comment: yes, of course, but the value is **not** computing to `auto` as I said before when I check the computed values of the browser... that's why confused...

Comment: @kukkuz The computed value of height isn't a percentage value or auto; it is a number of pixels. In this case the value 50% is computed in the same way as if you had set it to auto, as per the specs. You can see the computed value in browser dev tools, usually in the tab next to the css rules.

Comment: of course, that's where I was checking too... :) and it was showing `100px` and not `auto`

Comment: so is it like the browser will not show `auto` and show the value that it computes `auto`matically?

Comment: I still have my doubts, but I am happy that all browsers are consistent in this case and your logic seems reasonable :) Thanks a lot for the help!