# CSS: container with max-height, after that, a child div should start to scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a modal window that should be a small as possible, extend to 70% of the height. After that, the content of the modal (but not the modal itself) should start to scroll. I can't make this work.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="dialog"> 
    <div class="ui-root" >
        <div class="title" />
        <div class="body" />
        <div class="buttons" />
    </section>
</div>
```

This is the CSS idea:

```
 .dialog { max-height: 70% }
 .ui-root { display: flex }
 .body { flex: 1; overflow: scroll }
```

In words:

- If the body content is small, the height of .body can be the content height.
- If the body content is large, then .body starts to flex until it extends beyond the max-height of .dialog. Now it starts to scroll.

The problem:

- The max-height value is ignored.

Play with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/904/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ultimate solved this for myself was to enforce a strict and particular usage of flexbox within my dialog.

In turns out that if `<dialog>` has `max-height` and also `display: flex`, and the child elements are also `display: flex`, then the height calculation works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It is expected that the `max-height` is ignored here because it is applied to `dialog` and it does not affect its child element which is a `flexbox` (which should have a specific height).

> If the height of a `flexbox` is not specified, then you won't be able
>   to contain it within the parent element.

See how it solves itself when I give `max-height: 100%` to your `flexbox` (`ui-root`):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
}

.dialog {
      max-height: 50%;
      width: 40%;
      height: 50%;
}
.dialog.underflowing-dialog {
      position: absolute;      
}
.dialog.overflowing-dialog {
      position: absolute;      
      left: 50%;
}

.ui-root {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.ui-root article {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.underflowing-dialog .height-setting-content {
  height: 9px;
}
.overflowing-dialog .height-setting-content {
  height: 9999px;
}

.ui-root header {
    background-color: gray;
}
.ui-root footer {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog overflowing-dialog"> 
    <section class="ui-root" >
        <header class="title" >Should always be visible</header>
        <article class="body">  
          this should scroll
          <div class="height-setting-content"></div>
          and have the minimum height
        </article>
        <footer class="buttons" >Should always be visible</footer>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="dialog underflowing-dialog">
    <section class="ui-root" >
        <header class="title" >Should always be visible</header>
        <article class="body">  
          this should scroll
          <div class="height-setting-content"></div>
          and have the minimum height
        </article>
        <footer class="buttons" >Should always be visible</footer>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: @miracle2k so how does it look now? let me know your thoughts on this...

Comment: I'm so sorry - thanks for your suggestion, but trying it live I noticed that my jsdfiddle didn't map the real code; I updated the fiddle. The difference was that in the fiddle, the .dialog had a fixed height :/

Comment: okay, but you have to consider adding the `height: 50%` instead of `max-height: 50%` for your `dialog` (along with the `max-height: 100%` to `ui-root` as given in solution above) as [the children of a containing block will not respect `max-height` or `min-height` of the parent if height is not specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309205/height-calculation-by-browsers-containing-blocks-and-children)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The trick is to only make your content scrollable.

```css
.ui-root {
  width: 40%;
}

.ui-root header,
.ui-root footer {
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@keyframes scaling {
  from {
    height: 20px;
  }
  to {
    height: 999px;
  }
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: scaling 5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: scaling 5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: scaling 5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: scaling 5s linear infinite;
  animation: scaling 5s linear infinite;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<section class="ui-root">
  <header class="title">Should always be visible</header>
  <div class="scroll">
    <article class="content">
      this should scroll
    </article>
  </div>
  <footer class="buttons">Should always be visible</footer>
</section>
```