# Can anyone one figure this out CSS height quirk

Tags: css, tabs, height, flexbox

Ok this has me completely stumped, have been trying to fix for days with no avail.

I have used cbpFWTabs.js to split my content.

It however seems to behave very odd in that it ignores my height parameters and will set the div to the content size.

Only way to stop this is to set a fixed height, but i would like the div to dynamically resize to fill the rest of the screen and display scroll bars if it exceeds the content-wrap div (keeping the menubar fixed).

I've checked all parents, it just doesn't seem respond to anything i try :(

Example here:
http://numerco.com/wp-content/uploads/NUA/scratch.html

I'm sure its somthing trivial i missed but its driving me insane.

Thanks !

Comment: Its always a good thing in responsive design to fill the viewport with something like `height: 100%` for the outermost containers, so there is nothing wrong there! However take note of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309205/height-calculation-by-browsers-containing-blocks-and-children) which seems like a little bit unexpected behavior.

Comment: a solution might be to use `vh` units to fill the screen height... betweeen please add a snippet / fiddle instead of posting external links... Thanks!

Comment: ok this is very weird html height is set correctly and body here i get 975px but its child line-section-current or something is set too 1189px, its height parameter in set to 100% why any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have `height: 100%` on an element, that means it will inherit the height of its parent.

Thus, the first thing you need to do is set `height: 100%` on the `.container` so that its height takes up the full height of the `body`.

Then, set `height: 100%` on the `.container > section`. Then, the children know to stretch to the correct height (which has been propagated down from `body`).

This should solve the question in your OP. However, it seems like there's still something fishy going on with your heights. Feel free to ask another question if you need to.

Comment: thanks looks like a step in the right direction. i updated the page with your changes, it is filling out. but now its slightly over sized, just having a look now to try and work out whats going on :)

Comment: not sure whats scaling it up so high, height: 83% works well, but somthing tells me this shouldn't be happening like this..

Comment: yeah tried that its still too large :( this is completely baffling me now i not sure why it detects the browser height as 300px bigger than it really is and setting fixed height is not ideal at all as scroll bars will vanish on window resize

Comment: ha ok turns out i just had to apply the height of the content-wrap out as vh - (header height) and boom works great, thanks for your help guys!