# Height of Flex Div Not 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I have the body full height, but the containing div with a min-height of 100% does not fill. I'd like the blue to fill it's body container and flex align the internal divs.

https://codepen.io/steventnorris/pen/oVdKqY

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Text 1</div>
  <div>Text 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to go through 
[Height Calculation By Browsers : Containing Blocks and Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309205/height-calculation-by-browsers-containing-blocks-and-children). Clearly `height` and `min-height` are not the same thing in CSS.

---

Change `min-height` to `height` for your `body` and `html` - see demo below:

```css
html{
  height: 100%; /* changed to height */
  width: 100%;
}
body{
  height: 100%; /* changed to height */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Text 1</div>
  <div>Text 2</div>
</div>
```

You can also give `height: 100vh` to the `main` element to set an *instrinsic height* for the *flexbox* - see demo below:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh; /* full viewport height */
  background-color: green;
}
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Text 1</div>
  <div>Text 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For my specific use-case, I kept the min-heights as they were, but made them vh instead of percentiles, and that accomplished exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can give .main class a min-height of 100vh.

```
.main{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 min-height: 100vh;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background-color: blue;
 }
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYKzzM