# height doesn't change with %

Tags: html, css

I'm setting div's height with % values but doen`'t work but works with px values
this is the div:

```
<body>
    <div class="my-header">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Control de Cuotas</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the css:

```
.my-header{
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 241);
    min-height: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

with percentage  doesn't work with any value but using px

```
.my-header{
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 241);
    min-height: 85px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

The div change its height, what is the reason??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309205

Comment: note that min-height/height behave the same (the reference is the height of the parent element) so the duplicate is the canonical one