# what is the behavior of percentage height with min height?

Tags: html, css, height

When you give min-height to parent and percentage height to the child, the child doesn't get any height.

```css
.p {
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color:beige;
  
}

.c {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c"> hi </div>
</div>
```

But if you give explicit height to parent, even if it is smaller than min-height, the child gets a height, but it is relative to min-height and not height provided( when height < min-height)

```css
.p {
  min-height: 50vh;
  height: 1px;
  background-color:beige;
  
}

.c {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c"> hi </div>
</div>
```

1. First, I want to understand this behaviour
2. How can I give the height in percentage to the child with min-height only on the parent

Comment: height only sees height from the parent to calculate % value. min-height is another rule :( But it works the other way round indeed)

Comment: @G-Cyr i agree, but why in second case percentage is based on min-height and not height.. which is not happening in first snippet i have attached

Comment: basically you gave an explicit height so percentage will work and height will respect the min-height .. it's indeed a bit tricky, will try to find the relevant explanation

Comment: You are just lucky that it doesn't make it half a pixel high.  because min-height value is bigger than height value, height value is overwritten/updated to keep browser behavior coherent and avoid funny bugs

Comment: Exact question I've asked before :) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309205/height-calculation-by-browsers-containing-blocks-and-children

Comment: But you have one thing to mind: min-height:50vh + height:1px; is equal to height:50vh. Your container will not grow anymore passed this value. min-height becomes useless and inefficient.

Comment: @G-Cyr not exactly equal because we can add more *trouble* by applying a max-height with a value lower than 50vh and it will be ignored because min-height has higher priority than max-height but max-height more than height.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how percentage height works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height I am using this link because it was much easier to find, as mentioned in the other answer, spec link https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#value-def-percentage

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. **If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto.** A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block.

You will have to scroll down to find this (Specifications section)

In your case, since you did not specify the height of the parent, your child percentage height computes to auto which is what you saw in your example

here is how you can get percentage height to work without specifying a height of the parent, with position absolute

```css
.p {
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color:beige;
  position: relative;
}

.c {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="c"> hi </div>
</div>
```

Note - the height of your parents = the greater value between min-height and height, which is why your second case works

Honestly, adding a height of 1px as a work around to get the percentage to work for a child without defining a fixed height (since min-height overrides) is a pretty good work around.

Comment: why in second case percentage is with respect to min height and not height explicitly provided

Comment: The height of your parent is the greater value between height and min-height, so since 50vh > 1px, you get your 50% for the child. I added this part to the answer in case these comments gets lost

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you do not specify a height for the parent so according to the specs [`height doc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) the height of the child will be set to **auto** instead of the percentage.

> If the height of the containing block is **not specified explicitly** , and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to **auto**.

In the second case you set a specific height and a min-height. According to another spec regarding [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

> The element's height is set to the value of **min-height** whenever min-height is larger than max-height or height.

So just by setting `height:1px` on the **parent** ( so setting a specific height ) the value of `height:50%` of the **child** will compute to `50%` of the parent's height. Now, the parents height is not computed to `1px` but to the value of `min-height` . So the child 50% height will be 1/2 of min-height of parent.